# ¿Como puedo calcular el tamaño total de bytes que ocupa una tabla en mysql?

Tags: mysql

He creado tablas en mysql pero requiero saber cuanto ocupa en bytes, por ejemplo se que si he definido un campo int(7) este ocupara 4 bytes, pero cuanto ocupa un varchar(n) en byte como se calcula ese tamaño

Comment: ¿Quieres el tamaño total de la tabla, o el tamaño de cada campo individual?

Comment: Tamaño de cada campo individual en bytes y  totalizo para sacar el tamaño de la tabla

Comment: Pregunto porque el tamaño de la tabla entera no se obtiene simplemente sumando los campos individuales. La tabla ocupa espacio para otras cosas también. Luego hay los índices, etc.... Pero si es el tamaño individual de cada campo que quieres de todas maneras, esto lo puedes encontrar en la documentación ofial de MySQL dobre los diferentes tipos. Por ejemplo, para `varchar`, la respuesta se encuentra aquí: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html.

Comment: Pero si mi varchar es varchar(50)  como sabria la cantidad de bytes como es ese calculo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno encontre el patron para los varchar el tamaño en bytes se determina por la cantidad de caracteres mas 1, en el caso de los int y float es constante en 4 bytes

Comment: Podrías compartir tu fuentes por favor? Necesito ampliar en ese tema.

Comment: diego medina, disculpa ese día no pude responderte, por mi cumple, pero talves aun te sirve https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/1054.php